# Returning json response with status code and data in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, jsonresponse

I tried searching for solutions on how to return json response in laravel but after trying few variations i was lost on this matter, an explanations would be nice:

why is it that whenever i add a status codes in the `json()` function like this

```
response()->json(['hello'=> $someErrors], 401)
```

I dont get the `$someErrors` data in the console log of my js code
but when i remove it and do it like

```
response()->json($someErrors);
```

or

```
response($someErrors);
```

i get my `$someErrors` data in the console log of my js code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not generating valid renounce to catch in your view. Try to through json exception:

```
$api_errors = $validator->errors();
throw new HttpResponseException(
    response()
    ->json($result, $api_errors)
    ->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'text/plain', 'charset' => 'utf-8'])
);
```